# Netty does not retry connection on ConnectException

Tags: java, apache-camel, netty

I have 2 Camel routes:

```
from("jms:queue:" + queue + "?transacted=true")
        .bean(interfaceProcessor, "prepareMessage")
        .to("direct:interfaceRoute")
        .end();

from("direct:interfaceRoute")
        .errorHandler(noErrorHandler())
        .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.OutIn)
        .to("netty:tcp://" + address + ":" + port + "?clientMode=true&requestTimeout=" + requestTimeout + "&disconnect=true")
        .bean(interfaceProcessor, "doStuff");
```

The first route is triggered when a message is put on a JMS queue. The message is then processed in a bean and the return value is put on a separate route to send it to a remote host.

When something goes into the `direct:interfaceRoute`, Netty is supposed to open a new connection to a certain address/port as a client. This works fine, but when the remote host is not available I get a `ConnectException` and stops operating altogether. If this happens, it needs to keep retrying until the remote host is available.

I tried making the 'upper' route `transacted` and I removed any error handler on the route that does the actual sending on a socket. This works for a `ReadTimeoutException` (the remote host does not respond in time). When this happens, the message is resent until the remote host responds. I need the same handling for a `ConnectException`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its currently not supported. But we will add support for this in the next release. There is a ticket about this

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8894

Comment: Thank you for confirming this, I was suspecting as much as I couldn't find anything in the documentation about this. I will write my own socket for now and keep an eye on this issue.